# Yocto SDK-built Application on Embedded Linux - Shared Libraries Not Found

Tags: linux, cmake, embedded-linux, yocto

I am developing an application for an embedded Linux device using the Yocto SDK. My project depends on several shared libraries, and I've added them using the target_link_libraries in my CMake configuration. The project compiles successfully within the Yocto SDK environment.
The structur of my project looks like that:

```
project:
|- 3rd_party
|  |- some 3rd party libs as cmake subdirs
|- components
|  |- my own shared libraries
|- main
    |- main_application
```

However, when I copy the compiled binary to my embedded device and try to run it, I encounter an error indicating that the shared libraries cannot be found. I suspect this is due to a library path issue.

What steps should I take to resolve this issue and ensure that my application can find the required shared libraries when deployed on my embedded device?

Details:

- I've confirmed that the libraries are correctly linked during the
  build process.
- I've checked the presence of the shared libraries on the device, and
  they are in the expected directory.
- I've attempted to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on the device to specify the
  library directory, but the issue persists.
- The embedded device is running Linux, and I'm using SCP to copy files
  to it.
  The Yocto SDK is used for cross-compilation.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `I've checked the presence of the shared libraries on the device, and they are in the expected directory.` - but apparently not where your application expects them to be :) Running your app with strace should give some hints what locations it is looking at while searching for the lib-files.